# Editing HTML with JavaScript, but the two blocks of code only work by themselves

Tags: javascript

I am trying to edit the displayed text in the HTML with JavaScript, but the I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". If I comment out the first block of code, the second works, and if I comment out the second block, the first works.

```js
var updateStore = window.setInterval(function() {
  //Gold per Building
  document.getElementById("pickaxe-info").innerHTML = "Pickaxe <br> " + gameData.pickaxeProfit + " GPS <br> Producing " + gameData.pickaxeGold + " GPS<br>A sturdy pickaxe to mine gold with";
  document.getElementById("dwarf-info").innerHTML = "Dwarf  <br> " + gameData.dwarfProfit + " GPS each<br> Producing " + gameData.dwarfGold + " GPS<br>An assistant to help you mine gold";
  document.getElementById("goose-info").innerHTML = "Geese <br> " + gameData.gooseProfit + " GPS each<br> Producing " + gameData.gooseGold + " GPS<br>A nice goose that lays golden egg";
  document.getElementById("mine-info").innerHTML = "Gold Mine <br> " + gameData.mineProfit + " GPS each<br> Producing " + gameData.mineGold + " GPS<br>A new mine to mine gold in";
  document.getElementById("dragon-info").innerHTML = "Dragon <br> " + gameData.dragonProfit + " GPS each<br> Producing " + gameData.dragonGold + " GPS<br>A nice dragon to steal gold and hoard it";
  document.getElementById("stone-info").innerHTML = "Philosopher's Stone <br> " + gameData.stoneProfit + " GPS each<br> Producing " + gameData.stoneGold + " GPS<br>An alchemy stone that turns ordinary rocks into gold";
  document.getElementById("station-info").innerHTML = "Astroid-mining Station <br> " + gameData.stationProfit + " GPS each<br> Producing " + gameData.stationGold + " GPS<br>A space station that mines astroids for gold";
  document.getElementById("leprechaun-info").innerHTML = "Leprechaun <br> " + gameData.lepProfit + " GPS each<br> Producing " + gameData.leprechaunGold + " GPS<br>Uses magical leprechaun powers to find gold at the end of rainbows";
  document.getElementById("sheep-info").innerHTML = "Golden Sheep <br> " + gameData.sheepProfit + " GPS each<br> Producing " + gameData.sheepGold + " GPS<br>A cute round fluffy sheep with a golden fleece";
  document.getElementById("ray-info").innerHTML = "Mass Ray <br> " + gameData.rayProfit + " GPS each<br> Producing " + gameData.rayGold + " GPS<br>Turns mass into gold";
  document.getElementById("merger-info").innerHTML = "Neutron Star Merger<br> " + gameData.mergerProfit + " GPS each<br> Producing " + gameData.mergerGold + " GPS<br>Merges neutron stars to create gold (find what you want at it's source ;).";

  //Building Count
  document.getElementById("bTool").innerHTML = "Better Tools<br> Tool Level " + gameData.toolLevel + "<br> Cost: " + gameData.bToolCost + " Gold";
  document.getElementById("buyPickaxe").innerHTML = "Pickaxe<br> (You have " + gameData.pickaxeNumber + ") <br>Cost: " + gameData.buyPickaxeCost + " Gold";
  document.getElementById("hireDwarf").innerHTML = "Dwarf<br> (You have " + gameData.dwarfNumber + ") <br>Cost: " + gameData.hireDwarfCost + " Gold";
  document.getElementById("hireGoose").innerHTML = "Geese<br> (You have " + gameData.gooseNumber + ") <br>Cost: " + gameData.hireGooseCost + " Gold";
  document.getElementById("openMine").innerHTML = "Gold Mine<br> (You have " + gameData.mineNumber + ") <br>Cost: " + gameData.openMineCost + " Gold";
  document.getElementById("hireDragon").innerHTML = "Dragon<br> (You have " + gameData.dragonNumber + ") <br>Cost: " + gameData.hireDragonCost + " Gold";
  document.getElementById("buyStone").innerHTML = "Philosopher's Stone<br> (You have " + gameData.stoneNumber + ") <br>Cost: " + gameData.buyStoneCost + " Gold";
  document.getElementById("openStation").innerHTML = "Astroid-mining Station<br> (You have " + gameData.stationNumber + ") <br>Cost: " + gameData.openStationCost + " Gold";
  document.getElementById("hireLeprechaun").innerHTML = "Leprechaun<br> (You have " + gameData.leprechaunNumber + ") <br>Cost: " + gameData.hireLeprechaunCost + " Gold";
  document.getElementById("hireSheep").innerHTML = "Golden Sheep<br> (You have " + gameData.sheepNumber + ") <br>Cost: " + gameData.hireSheepCost + " Gold";
  document.getElementById("buyRay").innerHTML = "Mass Ray<br> (You have " + gameData.rayNumber + ") <br>Cost: " + gameData.buyRayCost + " Gold";
  document.getElementById("buyMerger").innerHTML = "Neutron Star Merger<br> (You have " + gameData.mergerNumber + ") <br>Cost: " + gameData.buyMergerCost + " Gold";
}, 500)
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="store-item" id="bTool" onclick="bTool()">
    <p class="store-display" id="tool-display">Better Tools <br>Tool Level 1<br>Cost: 10 Gold</p>
    <p class="store-info" id="tool-info">Better Tools <br> +1 gold per click<br>Better tools, better mining?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="store-item" id="buyPickaxe" onclick="buyPickaxe()">
    <p class="store-display" id="pickaxe-display">Pickaxe <br>(You have 0) <br>Cost: 25 Gold</p>
    <p class="store-info" id="pickaxe-info">Pickaxe <br> 0.5 GPS each<br> Producing 0 GPS<br>A sturdy pickaxe to mine gold with</p>
  </div>
  <div class="store-item" id="hireDwarf" onclick="hireDwarf()">
    <p class="store-display" id="dwarf-display">Dwarf <br>(You have 0) <br>Cost: 100 Gold</p>
    <p class="store-info" id="dwarf-info">Dwarf <br> 2 GPS each<br> Producing 0 GPS<br>An assistant to help you mine gold</p>
  </div>
  <div class="store-item" id="hireGoose" onclick="hireGoose()">
    <p class="store-display" id="goose-display">Goose <br>(You have 0) <br>Cost: 8,000 Gold</p>
    <p class="store-info" id="goose-info">Goose <br> 10 GPS each<br> Producing 0 GPS<br>A nice goose that lays golden eggs</p>
  </div>
  <div class="store-item" id="openMine" onclick="openMine()">
    <p class="store-display" id="mine-display">Gold Mine <br>(You have 0) <br>Cost: 25,000 Gold</p>
    <p class="store-info" id="mine-info">Gold Mine <br> 60 GPS each<br> Producing 0 GPS<br> A new mine to mine gold in</p>
  </div>
  <div class="store-item" id="hireDragon" onclick="hireDragon()">
    <p class="store-display" id="dragon-display">Dragon <br>(You have 0) <br>Cost: 200,000 Gold</p>
    <p class="store-info" id="dragon-info">Dragon <br> 2,000 GPS each<br> Producing 0 GPS<br> A nice dragon to steal gold and hoard it</p>
  </div>
  <div class="store-item" id="buyStone" onclick="buyStone()">
    <p class="store-display" id="stone-display">Philosopher's Stone <br>(You have 0) <br>Cost: 3,500,000 Gold</p>
    <p class="store-info" id="stone-info">Philosopher's Stone <br> 10,000 GPS each<br> Producing 0 GPS<br> An alchemy stone that turns ordinary rocks into gold</p>
  </div>
  <div class="store-item" id="openStation" onclick="openStation()">
    <p class="store-display" id="station-display">Astroid-mining Station <br>(You have 0) <br>Cost: 250,000,000 Gold</p>
    <p class="store-info" id="station-info">Astroid-mining Station <br> 85,000 GPS each<br> Producing 0 GPS<br> A space station that mines astroids for gold</p>
  </div>
  <div class="store-item" id="hireLeprechaun" onclick="hireLeprechaun()">
    <p class="store-display" id="leprechaun-display">Leprechaun <br>(You have 0) <br>Cost: 1,000,000,000 Gold</p>
    <p class="store-info" id="leprechaun-info">Leprechaun <br> 1,000,000 GPS each<br> Producing 0 GPS<br> Uses magical leprechaun powers to find gold at the end of rainbows</p>
  </div>
  <div class="store-item" id="hireSheep" onclick="hireSheep()">
    <p class="store-display" id="sheep-display">Golden Sheep <br>(You have 0) <br>Cost: 250,000,000,000 Gold</p>
    <p class="store-info" id="sheep-info">Golden Sheep <br> 10,000,000 GPS each<br> Producing 0 GPS<br> A cute round fluffy sheep with golden fleece</p>
  </div>
  <div class="store-item" id="buyRay" onclick="buyRay()">
    <p class="store-display" id="ray-display">Mass Ray each<br> Producing 0 GPS<br>(You have 0) <br>Cost: 2,000,000,000,000 Gold</p>
    <p class="store-info" id="ray-info">Mass Ray <br> 1,000,000,000 GPS each<br> Turns mass into gold</p>
  </div>
  <div class="store-item" id="buyMerger" onclick="buyMerger()">
    <p class="store-display" id="merger-display">Neutron Star Merger<br>(You have 0) <br>Cost: 200,000,000,000,000 Gold</p>
    <p class="store-info" id="merger-info">Neutron Star Merger<br> 10,000,000,000 GPS each<br> Producing 0 GPS<br> Merges neutron stars to create gold (find what you want at it's source :).</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the second block is deleting some elements with the ids that are used on the first block, so the second time is called that function, those elements no longer exist, and so you get the error

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!

Comment: you're welcome, keep in mind that `.innerHTML = ..` will delete the inner elements of that element, so for example `document.getElementById("buyPickaxe").innerHTML = ...` will delete the `#pickaxe-info` element inside him